# Rails Base64 decoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, base64

I have to implement a client and server for end-to-end encryption.

So if I am correctly informed, I need to encode and decode my keys with Base64.

> ArgumentError (string contains null byte):
>    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:46:in `register'

This is what I get just after the request reached my Server.

And that is the code i have written.

```
43 tempkey = Base64.decode64(params[:privkey_user_enc])
44    @user = User.new(:identity => params[:identity], :salt_masterkey => params[:salt_masterkey], :pubkey_user => params[:pubkey_user], :privkey_user_enc => tempkey)
45      if !(User.find_by_identity(@user.identity))
46          if @user.save
```

And a snippet from the key:

> LSFzoeT/7VLtWCQHEx3p3Nz3AfC7toACKRWELNC5E6CtSEsp6pZ7b4zldP\n2J5otJjjGSmVgg7e8XtndpAoI6ZJdBr/XeMoKNID9bs1kiWw2BAOduTWJ37a\nBAurnBZlOGycwvRXPmSDbMLSEyuCf53UTpskIhCkLDv21rW2qklIVC22Z+k6\n3dSRYZ5dQjPwhdfkaUgXwcRQFMazbdw/RSSNH0twcax7msHZms2iVlgvjElN\n+qi5Iu77J3DZCOE2fAo06WXALQfG2gOuzTWwlsVOW+iwj/tMypYzEAu+Y+kx\n51M0XlwRgAyRSqg7MMyT8OGC/jtJgc1A8gwSn7pz9cSnTCFUFh1eulE4pLpS\n4Gxm30aqHPCpNgvjJssNdntbdMxn10mfg7wzJNvSeFof90rSZb+PNWwvlYBZ\nQLjB1J9myQwq1+ptzvcgeskaRaGBWpSXyeo2HUCcsRNbajqjSViyheKKMWDb\n7H6tdlrIE+d1XcwIvczU9DbgtIB8gy8PBL6XI5KLSq9gzy/TSVahCeqURyA4\nnmT2luNxdggQLc7aY0aL03vNl5dun0Xem2rVCI3lFo2e4WH

I think I may have narrowed the problem down to `tempkey` but I am not quite sure.

I would really appreciate any help. I found nothing in the Internet that solved my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean end-to-end **en**cryption? (I.e., only encrypted data will be in transit, and it will only be decrypted by the final recipient.)

Comment: Yeah sorry. English is not my foreign language and I am a little tired.

Comment: No problem, it isn't my native language, either. Are you trying to persist the newly created user only if none with the same `identity` already exists in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have run into [this](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issue/198/argumenterror-string-contains-null-byte) bug which prevents you storing data with embedded nulls.

I would just store the key as-is (ie. in Base64 format) as this will have no nulls. Then... when you need the key for a crypto operation just Base64.decode64(@user.privkey_user_enc) before use.

Base64 is just a mechanism for converting binary data into a text string that can be easily stored/transmitted

Comment: I tried that. If I do it like that he throws an "Invalid Character" Exception.

Comment: Hmmmm... OK... Are any of the other params you are passing to User.new have non-ascii chars in them?  Try dumping them to the log or setting a breakpoint where you can check them. If there are non-ascii chars, you can Base64.encode64 them for easy storage.

Comment: Yeah, well. A Colleague of mine made a mistake within the Client. So now it works more or less. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad you are back on track. Good luck with the rest of the project.